# How to allow anon users to select contacts from civi in webform?

Tags: civicrm, webforms

I'm using civi and webforms to gather custom data, in this case an application for examination of a student, I have two contact fields; one for the user (student) and another for the examiner.

I have set the choices available from the examiner fieldset to only allow for contact belonging to our instructor group in civi as choices. Works great if you have civi permissions but not for anon users or users without civi permissions.